# File upload is not working in jenkins through java code

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am using following code to upload the file to application

```
String fileUploadPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator
    + "UploadPdfFile" + File.separator;

File file = new File(fileUploadPath);
File[] files = file.listFiles();
String name = null;
for (File f : files) {
    System.out.println(f.getName());
    name = f.getName();
}

// Copy your file's absolute path to the clipboard
StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(fileUploadPath + name);
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(ss, null);

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.delay(250);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.delay(150);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Above code is working on my local machine but when i am trying to run the same code in Jenkins which is located in different windows machine is Failing,
I am not understating why it is failing.

**Details:**

- OS= windows 10
- language= java
- selenium Version = 3.141.5
- Jenkins Version= 2.190.2
- java version =8

Can some help on this ?

Thanks

Comment: could you pls paste the console output of the jenkins?

Comment: it is not displaying any error, method get executed successfully but file is not uploaded

Comment: Are the files outputted?

Comment: No, It is a simple pdf file which i have to upload it in my application

Comment: In the for loop, you are outputting all files in the directory. So you should see some output somewhere. You are just using the last file in the directory. So you should see some text in the log.

Comment: Before you do listFiles(), try a check with Files.exists() and/or Files.isDirectory(file) and also do System.out.println(file) just to be sure you are checking at the right place.

Comment: file present at location, same code is working on my location machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

My upload file DOM structure is as shown in above Image:
From this I have created Unique x-path including 'input' tag.

x-path is as follow:

x-path=> `"//span[@class='ant-upload']/input"`

**Note:** It is mandatory to include 'input' tag in xpath.

After that I have used WebDriver default method, which work for me.

```
   String FileUploadPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ File.separator
    + "UploadFile"+ File.separator + "UploadFile.png";      
WebElement uploadElement = 
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ant-upload']/input"));
  uploadElement.sendKeys(FileUploadPath);
```

With this I am able to upload the file successfully.

**Observation:**
Jenkins is running in headless mode so it is not opening any file upload popup, so that my previous code (asked in question section) is failing, Now with above code (given in answer section) the popup will not appear, it will directly upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

Is the system property for the Jenkins service account set? If you have installed Jenkins as a service it uses the system account. Maybe the property is not set there.

If you are using Jenkinsfiles, you can use it like this:

```
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        environment { 
                user.dir= 'c:\users\jenkins'
            }
        steps {
            sh 'env'
            sh 'echo $AOEU'
        }
    }
}
```

This plugin might help: [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)

Comment: I have kept my file in my automation framework from that location i am uploading, i am not using jenkins file